# Stop image blinking on image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an image slideshow, however, I have come across a problem.Every time I click to move the slideshow the next image blinks.How do I avoid this I would like it to just slide in smoothly.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: parseInt(slideWidth) * 3 +"px",
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li img{
  max-width:100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0% 0%;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Very Simple Slider</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
  <div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next"></a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/e3bb/f/2012/155/0/c/naruto_unleashed_by_sketch_gfx-d529cho.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://assets.rbl.ms/6450955/980x.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="http://tampascene.com/images/new-images/parks-weedonisland.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_option"> </div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

I am not sure how to do this if you have any guides or pointers it would be great And if this question needs improving it wouldn't hurt just trying to tell me instead of just downvoting I am only 13 years and still learning Thank You in advance.

Comment: Just from a quick look at your code it seems like upon clicking, first you move the list left or right, then drop in the image that will fill in the gap. Wouldn't it stop the flash if you first put the new image in its proper position, and then animated the entire list?

Comment: Ok sir could you just show me how to do that as I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can fade in the image by changing all the `prependTo` and `appendTo` statements thusly:

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
```

becomes

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').hide().prependTo('#slider ul').fadeIn(500);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/effydr22/5/) containing the updated code. You can change the number in `fadeIn(x)` to however many `x` milliseconds you like.